# Need read and write to Mysql in flink job

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to use table API's but getting an error

TableEnvironment fbTableEnv = BatchTableEnvironment.create(fbEnv);
[ERROR]                                                         ^^^^^^
[ERROR] This static method of interface BatchTableEnvironment can only be accessed as BatchTableEnvironment.create
[ERROR] 1 problem (1 error)
[ERROR]

`ExecutionEnvironment fbEnv = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();`
`TableEnvironment fbTableEnv = BatchTableEnvironment.create(fbEnv);`

Answer (score 1):

`BatchTableEnvironment` only exists for legacy reasons. For regular SQL and batch jobs, we recommend to use `TableEnvironment.create` it is unified and can work on batch and streaming data.

Comment: EnvironmentSettings environmentSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().build();  TableEnvironment tableEnvironment =TableEnvironment.create(environmentSettings);




[ERROR]  TableEnvironment tableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.create(environmentSettings);
[ERROR]                                                       ^^^^^^
[ERROR] This static method of interface TableEnvironment can only be accessed as TableEnvironment.create